# How do I change a fragment's view/button's visibility from an activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

As the title suggests, I'm trying to change a fragment's view/button's visibility from an activity.

Fragment's code:

```
package nus.is3261.kotlinapp


import android.content.Context
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Button

// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private const val ARG_PARAM1 = "param1"
private const val ARG_PARAM2 = "param2"

/**
 * A simple [Fragment] subclass.
 *
 */
class SettingFragment : Fragment() {
    private var listener:SettingFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener? = null

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_setting, container, false)
        val signIn = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.btn_sign_in)
        signIn.setOnClickListener {
            onButtonPressed("signIn")
        }
        val signOut = view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn_sign_out)
        signOut.setOnClickListener {
            onButtonPressed("signOut")
        }
        return view
    }

    fun changeVisibility(isSignedIn : Boolean){
        if (isSignedIn) {
            val signIn = view?.findViewById<View>(R.id.btn_sign_in)
            signIn?.visibility = View.GONE
            val signOut = view?.findViewById<View>(R.id.btn_sign_out)
            signOut?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        } else {
            val signIn = view?.findViewById<View>(R.id.btn_sign_in)
            signIn?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            val signOut = view?.findViewById<View>(R.id.btn_sign_out)
            signOut?.visibility = View.GONE

        }
    }

    fun onButtonPressed(str: String) {
        listener?.onFragmentInteraction(str)
    }

    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        if (context is SettingFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            listener = context
        } else {
            throw RuntimeException(context.toString() + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener")
        }
    }

    override fun onDetach() {
        super.onDetach()
        listener = null
    }

    interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        fun onFragmentInteraction(str: String)
    }

}
```

As you can already see, I have the changeVisibility function to change the visibility of the buttons already set up. Now, how can I invoke these functions from the main activity ? 
I tried this from the main activity but it does not work sadly:

```
    private fun updateUI(user: FirebaseUser?) {
        if (user != null) {
//            tvStatus.text = "Google User email: " + user.email!!
//            tvDetail.text = "Firebase User ID: " + user.uid
            val fragment = SettingFragment()
            fragment.changeVisibility(true)
//            btn_sign_in.visibility = View.GONE
//            layout_sign_out_and_disconnect.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        } else {
//            tvStatus.text = "Signed Out"
//            tvDetail.text = null
            val fragment = SettingFragment()
            fragment.changeVisibility(false)
//            btn_sign_in.visibility = View.VISIBLE
//            layout_sign_out_and_disconnect.visibility = View.GONE
        }
    }
```

Here is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/dracula"
    tools:context=".SettingFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_sign_in"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:visibility="visible"
            tools:visibility="gone" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_sign_out"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:visibility="gone"
            tools:visibility="visible"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/draculalight"
            android:textColor="@color/green"
            android:text="@string/signout" />

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Well you are using view?.setVisibility. Remove the ? and see if you crash. I'm guessing you aren't finding the view that you are attempting to toggle visibility on. If that doesn't work, please share your xml file.

Comment: it does not work, ok ill provide my xml file

Comment: What doesn't work? I asked you to reveal if you are crashing without the ? but yes provide the xml.

Comment: Try putting this (val signIn = view?.findViewById<View>(R.id.btn_sign_in)
            signIn?.visibility = View.GONE) inside the onResume of your fragment and tell me if that hides it. I'm wondering if you are touching it outside of the lifecycle. Also put a breakpoint to verify it is hit.

Comment: oops sry haha, when i remove the `?` it underlines that sentence in red and tells me that `Only safe or null asserted calls are allowed on a nullable reveiver of type View?`

Comment: yes remove it from your view declaration as well. i.e.  val signIn = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.btn_sign_in)
            signIn.visibility = View.GONE

Comment: Or set a breakpoint after you find it and confirm you actually have a view

Comment: When i remove the `?` it says compilation error when I compile

Comment: Please show the code where you add the fragment to the activity

Comment: but now when I add the `?`along with your `onResume` suggestion, it removes the button, which shows that the fragment part works, the error is probably in the main activity where i reference the fragment i think

Comment: how i referenced the fragment is `val fragment = SettingFragment()`, it is in the 2nd picture. However, im not sure if thats the correct way to do so though.

Comment: You are correct, that is not the way to do it ;). I'll post an answer with details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so you have a couple of issues, but it's probably best if I just provide a thorough step by step for you. So let's start from the beginning.

**So first the Issue**

You are referencing the wrong memory. First you put a fragment into your xml, then you new up a different instance of it, so it's like pouring a cup of coffee, then drinking out of a new empty cup and wondering why the coffee isn't in there.

**Now for the solution.**

First your MainActivity (or parent activity of the fragment) MUST contain the element of the fragment you are trying to include. You have a couple of options to do this. Let's start with the simplest way assuming it is a static fragment that will not be swapped out.

**OPTION 1 (Fixed Fragment)**

```
<ParentActivityLayoutOfYourChoice>

    <fragment
        android:name="com.yourpath.FooFragment"
        android:id="@+id/fooFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</ParentActivityLayoutOfYourChoice>
```

Then in the Activity you would simply create a member variable and access it like:

```
//lateinit only if you guarantee it will be there in the oncreate
private lateinit var fooFragment: FooFragment
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    fooFragment = findViewById(R.id.fooFragment)
}

fun btnSignIn_onClick(){
    //onSuccess
    fooFragment.isSignedIn(true)
}
```

**OPTION 2 (Dynamic Fragments)**

```
<ParentActivityLayoutOfYourChoice>

   <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragPlaceholder"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</ParentActivityLayoutOfYourChoice>
```

Then of course you can create the Fragment in your onCreate or appropriate place (such as drawer switching fragments) and swap it into the place holder.

*EXAMPLE:*

//Inside MainActivity (or parent activity)

```
 //lazy will new it up the first time you use it.
 private val mFooFragment by lazy {
    FooFragment()
 }

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    swapFragment(mFooFragment) //will auto new the fragment with lazy
}

//Let's start simple before I show you thorough
fun swapFragment(fragment: Fragment){
     val fragmentManager = supportFragmentManager
     val fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
     fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragPlaceholder, fragment)
     fragmentTransaction.commit() //puts the fragment into the placeholder
}

fun btnSignIn_onClick(){
    //onSuccess
    mFooFragment.isSignedIn(true)
}
```

*Now, before we go further, I feel it's important that I tell you that if you are swapping fragments dynamically there is MUCH more to it. You should handle the bundle, you should know if you are hiding, showing, replacing, etc.. There are many ways to handle the transaction. When changing your fragment out, you have to decide if you are hiding or removing. It will affect the lifecycle for onResume vs onCreate when you put them back, so manage it wisely.

I have built a simple swapFragment method that I use in almost all my projects in a BaseActivity. I'll share that now just to be thorough.

***EXAMPLE OF STORING SELECTED FRAGMENT AND CONTROLLING THE SWAPPING OF FRAGMENTS DYNAMICALLY IN A BASE ACTIVITY***

```
    private var mSelectedFragment: BaseFragment? = null

    protected fun swapFragment(fragment: BaseFragment, @Nullable bundle: Bundle?, hideCurrentFrag: Boolean = false) {
    if (fragment.isVisible) {
        A35Log.e(mClassTag, "swapFragment called on already visible fragment")
        return
    }

    A35Log.v(mClassTag, "swapFragment( ${fragment.javaClass.simpleName} )")
    val currentFragBundle = fragment.arguments
    if (currentFragBundle == null && bundle != null) {
        fragment.arguments = bundle
        A35Log.v(mClassTag, "current bundle is null, so setting new bundle passed in")
    } else if (bundle != null) {
        fragment.arguments?.putAll(bundle)
        A35Log.v(mClassTag, "current fragment bundle was not null, so add new bundle to it")
    }

    //make sure no pending transactions are still floating and not complete
    val fragmentManager = supportFragmentManager
    fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions()
    val fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()

    //Make sure the requested fragment isn't already on the screen before adding it
    if (fragment.isAdded) {
        A35Log.v(mClassTag, "Fragment is already added")
        if (fragment.isHidden) {
            A35Log.v(mClassTag, "Fragment is hidden, so show it")
            fragmentTransaction.show(fragment)
            if(hideCurrentFrag) {
                A35Log.v(mClassTag, "hideCurrentFlag = true, hiding current fragment $mSelectedFragment")
                fragmentTransaction.hide(mSelectedFragment!!)
            }else{
                A35Log.v(mClassTag, "hideCurrentFlag = false, removing current fragment $mSelectedFragment")
                fragmentTransaction.remove(mSelectedFragment!!)
            }
        }else{
            A35Log.v(mClassTag, "Fragment is already visible")
        }
    }else if(mSelectedFragment == null){
        A35Log.v(mClassTag,"mSelectedFragment = null, so replacing active fragment with new one ${fragment.javaClass.simpleName}")
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragPlaceholder, fragment)
    }else{
        A35Log.v(mClassTag, "Fragment is not added, so adding to the screen ${fragment.javaClass.simpleName}")
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragPlaceholder, fragment)
        if(hideCurrentFrag) {
            A35Log.v(mClassTag, "hideCurrentFlag = true, hiding current fragment $mSelectedFragment")
            fragmentTransaction.hide(mSelectedFragment!!)
        }else{
            A35Log.v(mClassTag, "hideCurrentFlag = false, removing current fragment $mSelectedFragment")
            fragmentTransaction.remove(mSelectedFragment!!)
        }
    }

    A35Log.v(mClassTag, "committing swap fragment transaction")
    fragmentTransaction.commit()
    A35Log.v(mClassTag, "mSelectedFragment = ${fragment.javaClass.simpleName}")
    mSelectedFragment = fragment
}
```

All Examples are provided in Kotlin since that is where Android is headed and you should be learning in Kotlin rather than Java if you are not already. If you are working with Java, then you can paste this into a Java file and I believe it will offer to translate it to Java for you.

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

This solved it for me in the end:

```
    private fun updateUI(user: FirebaseUser?) {
        if (user != null) {

//            tvStatus.text = "Google User email: " + user.email!!
//            tvDetail.text = "Firebase User ID: " + user.uid

            var fragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("setting") as SettingFragment
            fragment.changeVisibility(true)
//            btn_sign_in.visibility = View.GONE
//            layout_sign_out_and_disconnect.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        } else {
//            tvStatus.text = "Signed Out"
//            tvDetail.text = null
            var fragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("setting") as SettingFragment
            fragment.changeVisibility(false)
//            btn_sign_in.visibility = View.VISIBLE
//            layout_sign_out_and_disconnect.visibility = View.GONE
        }
    }
```

Comment: Rajdeep, I know this may work for you, but you should not be finding by tag, you should have an ID on your fragment or put it in at runtime. Please review my answer to get this managed in the recommended way.